# [Help Needed ]execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, trigger

```java
public class AccountOwner {
    
    Public static void AccountOwnerUpdate(List<Account>Listofaccounts){
        Set<id> Ids = New set<id>();
        For(Account acc: LIstofaccounts){
            Ids.add(Acc.id);
        }
        
        map<id ,account> newacc = new map<id,account>([select id, name from account where id in: Ids]);
        
        for(Account Acc: LIstofaccounts)
        {
            Account acc1 = newacc.get(Acc.id);
            Acc.Account_Owner_Name__c = acc1.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```java
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, After Insert, Before Delete, After Delete, after update)

  
    if(trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if(trigger.isInsert)
        {
            AccountOwner.AccountOwnerUpdate(Trigger.new);
        }
```

Comment: N.B. sfdcfox answer - the formula field is the right approach

Answer (score 2):

In a before insert trigger, the records do not yet have an ID. It appears you're trying to query for owner. That would look something like this:

```
Map<Id, String> ownerNames = new Map<Id, String>();
for(Account record: listOfAccounts) {
  ownerNames.put(record.OwnerId, null);
}
for(User record: [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id = :ownerNames.keySet()]) {
  ownerNames.put(record.Id, record.Name);
}
for(Account record: listOfRecords) {
  record.Account_Owner_Name__c = ownerNames.get(record.OwnerId);
}
```

As an aside, I would consider not doing this; you could use a Formula Field to display the value on-demand when the field is queried.